# media css not reflect in mobile magento 2

Tags: css, magento2.4, porto-theme, mobile-device

I am making responsive design for mobile view. I have installed Porto Magento 2 theme. Porto theme provides css file custom design changes. I have made custom changes in `custom.css` file.
Porto theme put `custom.css` file in following path. Magento 2 hosted on nginx server.

```
/pub/media/porto/web/css/custom.css
```

and `custom.css` file imported via below code in `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/Porto/Smartwave_Porto/templates/html/head.phtml`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo $_helper->getPortoWebDir().'css/custom.css'; ?>">
```

Now the problem is if I do changes in `custom.css` its not refecting in my mobile. It just reflect on my PC in responsive view(sometimes I have to do hard refresh on PC to check made chages). When I checked in my mobile it's not reflect changes made in `custom.css` file.

**Below operation I did to show reflected css changes,but no luck**

I clear and flush cache

I disabled the cache and checked in my mobile but still show old changes.

I ran `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

I run index command but still in my mobile showing old css changes.

Currectly, Magento website mode is developer.

cleared `generated` folder

Why its not reflect on the `custom.css`
I have an doubt. This `custom.css` located in `/pub/media/porto/web/css/custom.css` path is correct according magento 2 standard ?

Please Give me solution.I am tired of this situation.

Comment: I suggest you to not directly edit porto theme files, it will get override on theme update.create a child theme of porto, add custom CSS file and add your changes there!

Comment: @Pawan thanks, I created new css file in Magento_Theme module. Now my new css reflect whenever I soft refresh the page

Comment: welcome @Niraj ..